# AWS Docker deployment not exposing port to outside world with Dockerrun file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a spring-boot application to AWS using a docker image, i need to be able to connect remotely to the application with hawtio console to monitor behavior. I have a Dockerfile created and an Dockerrun.aws.json file, for example, the dockerfile has EXPOSE 8080, and the Dockerrun is:

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
"Ports": [
  {
    "ContainerPort": 8080,
    "HostPort": 5000
  }
]
}
```

The AWS EB instance has the port 5000 opened (I tested it), but the Hawtio console does not connect to the application. Can someone point me in the right direction about how to properly expose the port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EB, then how are you specifying which docker image to use?

This information needs to be specified inside of the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, which is missing in the example that you have provided.

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "path to the image's repository",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": 8080,
            "HostPort": 5000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: yup, sorry missed that line on the post. Anyways I managed to solve the problem, AWS EB was starting the app on port 5000 , so I just had to set the containerPort to 5000 on the dockerrun.aws.json and EXPOSE 5000 in the Dockerfile